# getQuantityString(id, quantity, formatArgs) not working for Korean strings

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have my plural strings setup as such:

```xml
    <plurals name="count_video">
        <item quantity="other">%동영상 %d개</item>
    </plurals>
    <plurals name="count_photo">
        <item quantity="other">%사진 %d개</item>
    </plurals>
```

And I'm getting the following exception message:

```java
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '사'
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2782)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2812)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.<init>(Formatter.java:2625)
        at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2558)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2505)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2459)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2870)
```

I've tried replacing my `%d` with `%s` but nothing seems to work. I'm curious if this is a bug with Android or if I'm missing something.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with `\u0025사진 %d개`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Caveat: I have absolutely no knowledge of Korean, so this is just what I can see as an English speaker.)*

The start of `count_photo`'s item is `"%사"`. The same system that tries to parse `%d` or `%s` sees this combination and believes it to be a format specifier. I'm assuming that you just want the `"%"` character to appear in your string; this is achieved by doubling the `%` in your string.

```
<plurals name="count_video">
    <item quantity="other">%%동영상 %d개</item>
</plurals>
<plurals name="count_photo">
    <item quantity="other">%%사진 %d개</item>
</plurals>
```

Comment: I also have no knowledge of Korean, but I've figured out that that % sign is not supposed to be there... Thanks for pointing that out lol

Comment: This sentence is similar to 'Pencil : 2 dozen'. -> 'Pencel : %d dozen'. I think that first % sign is errata